# Why does the application portal ask 'To what other programs/universities are you applying?' while applying in US universities?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states

I am applying for higher studies in US universities. Every time I fill up the online form, there is a section where they asked which other universities or programs I am applying too? Why do they ask these questions? Do they check where I am applying?
What if I wrote a university name but later drop the idea to apply?

Comment: Do you mean the online application of an individual university or something more general? There are generalized portals for application, but I thought they were used primarily for undergraduate applications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do graduate school application forms ask applicants to name the other schools to which he/she is applying?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/why-do-graduate-school-application-forms-ask-applicants-to-name-the-other-school)

Comment: Also related: [PhD application asking what other insitution I am applying to, how to answer?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5446/68109)

Comment: I think they're much more likely to use the information for internal statistics and for grant applications rather than the reasons mentioned in the Q&A linked by GoodDeeds. There might be some consideration of whether applicants are likely to go someplace else, but I don't think programs are going to play those games much when they think a particular student is a good fit. Maybe a bit different if you spend your entire interview talking about how great Harvard is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions referenced by GoodDeeds covers most of your question - the why. For the rest:

In the US it would probably be impossible (illegal) for one university to query another about a student's application, so, no, they don't check.

And there will be no consequences if you list a school and then change your mind.

Don't feel any special obligation to answer such a question. I actually doubt that they use such a question to determine whether to accept you or not. It could be counterproductive for everyone.