# Is redacting the names of other grad schools I'm applying to in my unofficial GRE and TOEFL score report acceptable?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, united-states, application

I've been asked to upload these reports in the admissions form but both of them combined mention names of several of the US math grad schools I'm applying to for Fall 2023. I've read in other posts here that sharing that information is not necessary and hence I've declined to answer questions regarding other places I'm applying to in the application form. Would it be considered okay if I redacted these school names and mentioned that it was done to hide private information unrelated to the scores or would it be considered "tampering" with the score report?

Comment: Why? I mean, all schools know you are applying elsewhere. Nobody is going to pay attention to the list of names.

Comment: How do you think it is advantageous to fail to supply information that is asked for? It makes you seem a bit paranoid, actually.

Comment: @Buffy I took the advice mentioned here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/why-do-graduate-school-application-forms-ask-applicants-to-name-the-other-school and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/phd-application-asking-what-other-insitution-i-am-applying-to-how-to-answer

Comment: @JonCuster I took the advice mentioned here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/phd-application-asking-what-other-insitution-i-am-applying-to-how-to-answer and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/why-do-graduate-school-application-forms-ask-applicants-to-name-the-other-school

Comment: Note your situation is a little different - they aren't asking you, it is some additional information that slips through. And, just because you have listed schools does not mean you will actually apply to all or any of them. Schools that second-guess their decisions based on random scraps of information are going to get what they deserve.