# I don't want to disclose "other schools" in my application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

I am making a graduate application that requires me to fill "other schools" that I am applying to. It is not a mandatory field. If I choose not to fill, will my application be negatively impacted? Why do they want this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PhD application asking what other insitution I am applying to, how to answer?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/phd-application-asking-what-other-insitution-i-am-applying-to-how-to-answer)